# Where to download BibLaTEX

Tags: latex, bibtex, biblatex

I'm trying to write my thesis using overleaf, but having trouble with the referencing. I've been told to use BibLaTEX but it doesn't seem to be formatting correctly see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSyg8.png). From what I gather it's because I don't have the external software downloaded, but I'm confused as to what specifically I need and where to find it. I thought I downloaded this from CTAN, but all I found was a folder of .bib files and I'm not sure how that helps? [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gof1X.png) is the error message I recieve :/

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Here is my code, I try changing the style and the brackets in my doc change (but not the citation).

This is my new ref.bib

```
@book{williams_transmission_2008,
    location = {New York},
    edition = {2nd ed},
    title = {Transmission electron microscopy: a textbook for materials science},
    isbn = {978-0-387-76500-6},
    shorttitle = {Transmission electron microscopy},
    pagetotal = {4},
    publisher = {Springer},
    author = {Williams, David B. and Carter, C. Barry},
    date = {2008},
    keywords = {Materials, Microscopy, Transmission electron microscopy}
}
```

And this is my new test document, and the same image issue [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kap3x.png)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=science, citestyle=numeric, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref} % the ref.bib file

\begin{document}

Hi there, Stackoverflowers \cite{williams_transmission_2008}


\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need external software, overleaf has biblatex installed and will normally run it automatically. Can you make a [mre] that reproduces your problem? Please also include the content of `FirstLibrary.bib`

Comment: Please don't show us code fragments! Make a small but compilable test document that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hopefully this should be clearer now :)

Comment: Thanks for updating the code! There is a syntax error, it should be `\addbibresource{ref.bib}`

Comment: What's a bit strange is that overleaf seems to be using bibtex instead of biber. Try to click this button https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw5Ul.png to clear all the auxiliary files and the recompile

Comment: With the added .bib  it seems to work on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jcrjdncbytwg

Comment: Thank you! I cleared the cached files and made sure the .bib was there too so it compiled on the test doc but not my main one but found a new error within my bibliography that shouldn't have been there, and it worked after I deleted it!

`@misc{noauthor_notitle_nodate
}`